# AOSP: Can't get prebuilt static libraries into their intermediary folders in order to link to other modules

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to use prebuilt static libraries and link them to another
static library that I'm building in the AOSP build. The prebuilts are 
dependencies for which I have architecture specific versions.

The Core/App Module depends on the opencv prebuilds. Here is my folder structure

```
Core
├── Android.mk
├── Core
│   ├── Android.mk
│   ├── App
│   │   ├── Android.mk
|   |   | ...
│   ├── App.h
│   ├── Base
│   │   ├── Algorithm.cpp
│   │   ├── Algorithm.h
|   |   |   Android.mk
|   |   | ...
│   ├── Base.h
│   ├── Core.h
│   ├── GL
│   │   ├── Android.mk
│   │   └── GLWarpVertexRenderer.h
|   |   | ...
│   ├── GL.h
│   ├── Log
│   │   ├── Android.mk
|   |   | ...
│   ├── Log.h
└── Vendor
    ├── Android.mk
    ├── core-libs
    │   ├── opencv
    │   │   ├── Android
    │   │   │   ├── cmake_android_all.sh
    │   │   │   └── sdk
    │   │   │       └── native
    │   │   │           ├── 3rdparty
    │   │   │           │   └── libs
    |   |   |           |  ... 
    │   │   │           ├── jni
    │   │   │           │   ├── android.toolchain.cmake
    │   │   │           │   ├── include
    │   │   │           │   │   ├── opencv
    │   │   │           │   │   │   ├── cvaux.h
    |   |   |           |   |   |   ...
    │   │   │           │   │   └── opencv2
    │   │   │           │   │       ├── core
    │   │   │           └── libs
    │   │   │               ├── arm64-v8a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_core.a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_features2d.a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.a
    │   │   │               │   └── libopencv_video.a
    │   │   │               ├── armeabi-v7a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_core.a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_features2d.a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.a
    │   │   │               │   └── libopencv_video.a
    │   │   │               ├── x86
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_core.a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_features2d.a
    │   │   │               │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.a
    │   │   │               │   └── libopencv_video.a
    │   │   │               └── x86_64
    │   │   │                   ├── libopencv_core.a
    │   │   │                   ├── libopencv_features2d.a
    │   │   │                   ├── libopencv_imgproc.a
    │   │   │                   └── libopencv_video.a
    ├── Eigen
    |   ├── ...
    |
    └── fmt
        ├── Android.mk
              ...
  245 directories, 1743 files
```

#### Android.mk file for the Vendor folder.

It contains one built static lib and four prebuilds of both 32 & 64 bit flavor

```
#This build fmt and also exports the inlcude path to Eigen
#Link this with all Core components as a dependency

ROOT_DIR := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH := $(ROOT_DIR)/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_core_prebuilt
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_arm := armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES_arm64 := arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../jni/include
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_features2d_prebuilt
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both 
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .a
LOCAL_SRC_FILE_arm := armeabi-v7a/libopencv_features2d.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILE_arm64 := arm64-v8a/libopencv_features2d.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../jni/include 
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_imgproc_prebuilt
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both 
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .a
LOCAL_SRC_FILE_arm := armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILE_arm64 := arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../jni/include 
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_video_prebuilt
LOCAL_MULTILIB := both 
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .a
LOCAL_SRC_FILE_arm := armeabi-v7a/libopencv_video.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILE_arm64 := arm64-v8a/libopencv_video.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../jni/include 
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)


LOCAL_PATH := $(ROOT_DIR)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -fexceptions

LOCAL_MODULE := com.rylo.coreDeps

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/fmt/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/fmt/include \
                   $(LOCAL_PATH)/Eigen  

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := fmt/src/format.cc


include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

#### The Android.mk file of the library (Core/App) that is built by AOSP and depends on the prebuilt static STATIC_LIBRARIES

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..\
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Vendor/Eigen    

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-error -Wno-mismatched-tags
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../.. 
LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-error -Wno-mismatched-tags

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-cpp-files-under, . )

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := com.rylo.coreDeps \
                  opencv_core_prebuilt \
              opencv_features2d_prebuilt \
              opencv_imgproc_prebuilt \
              opencv_video_prebuilt

LOCAL_MODULE := com.rylo.coreApp

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I have not added anything to the PRODUCT_PACKAGES of the device config file. I expect the resulting Core/App library to be able to find its dependencies 
which it seems to during the build however it looks like the prebuilt targets are not getting copied to the Intermediary folders. Primarily it looks like the copy command for the PREBUILT is copying the $LOCAL_PATH as a folder and not the SRC file.

Here is the build output Log

```
[ 66% 2/3] glob vendor/*/*/*/*/*/Android.bp
[  1% 3/155] target Prebuilt: opencv_video_pr...ebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a)
FAILED: out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_video_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_video_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a ) && (cp vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/ out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_video_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a )"
cp: omitting directory ‘vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/’
[  2% 4/155] target Prebuilt: opencv_video_pr...ebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a)
FAILED: out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_video_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_video_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a ) && (cp vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/ out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_video_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a )"
cp: omitting directory ‘vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/’
[  3% 5/155] target Prebuilt: opencv_features...t_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a)
FAILED: out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_features2d_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_features2d_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a ) && (cp vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/ out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_features2d_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a )"
cp: omitting directory ‘vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/’
[  3% 6/155] target Prebuilt: opencv_imgproc_...uilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a)
FAILED: out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a ) && (cp vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/ out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a )"
cp: omitting directory ‘vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/’
[  4% 7/155] target Prebuilt: opencv_imgproc_...uilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a)
FAILED: out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a ) && (cp vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/ out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_imgproc_prebuilt.a )"
cp: omitting directory ‘vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/’
[  5% 8/155] target Prebuilt: opencv_features...t_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a)
FAILED: out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_features2d_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_features2d_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a ) && (cp vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/ out/target/product/qcs605/obj_arm/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_features2d_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_features2d_prebuilt.a )"
cp: omitting directory ‘vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/’
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Please note the following

```
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/qcs605/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/opencv_video_prebuilt_intermediates/opencv_video_prebuilt.a ) && (cp vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/
```

**Why is it copying `vendor/rylo/Core/Vendor/core-libs/opencv/Android/sdk/native/libs/` which is the LOCAL_PATH variable instead of the 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES variable contents?**

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Kartik

Comment: Any luck in finding an answer?

Comment: No ... And then I was no longer working on the platform.